# GraphQL: Returning null vs Throwing Error

Tags: graphql

In case of errors, I always wonder whether I should return `null` or throw an error.

Let's say I have a type `Person`:

```
type Person {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
}
```

I want to let the client search for a specific user. This could be done in 2 ways:

Using a nullable type and possibly returning `null` when no user is found:

```
type Query {
    getPerson(firstName: String!): Person
}
```

Using a non-nullable type and throwing an error when no user is found:

```
type Query {
    getPerson(firstName: String!): Person!
}
```

Is there a right way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question!

First I want to argue that the "errors" part of the response is realy only for developer errors (that means errors that are cause by a developer, either on the backend or on the frontend). For error happening when the API is misused, e.g. wrong arguments are supplied (HTTP 400-403), or something went wrong internally (HTTP 500). In this case something is broken and there is no action required by the user but by the developer. The not found (HTTP 404) is very special since it is often caused by the user of your APP (e.g. you try to access a profile page that does not exist). In this case we want to give feedback directly to the user. "This profile does not exist *Go back to homepage*" Most client tools don't handle the GraphQL errors very well. This is why errors that should be shown to the user should be part of your response schema. [This awesome blog post](https://itnext.io/the-definitive-guide-to-handling-graphql-errors-e0c58b52b5e1) goes into more detail on the topic.

Now I don't think that you need to return a dedicated `GetPersonPayload` type in your API but it is certainly a possibility:

```
type GetPersonPayload {
  person: Person
  errors: [PayloadError!]!
}

type Query {
   getPerson(firstName: String!): GetPersonPayload
}
```

To summarize: I would definitely return a nullable person and - depending on how futureproof/enterprise your schema should be - you might even want to return a special payload type as described in the linked article.

Comment: Would you say that I should throw an error only for unintended errors? Because searching for a non-existing person is something that's very likely to happen.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that enduser errors should never be thrown but instead returned within the schema in a dedicated error object type. So a user input should never lead to an error in the "errors" part of the response since graphql clients are horrible at handling them and the returned null value in the broken field very likely breaks your schema contract.